# How to display folder/directory selector pop up in groovy script in SOAP UI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am working on SOAP UI testing in which I am writing groovy scripts. At one place I have to popup directory selector using groovy. I know how to popup normal message windows. but I am not aware of displaying popup for directory selector.

Can someone suggest me a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since groovy can execute java code, you can simply use the java swing component [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) to do so. You can use the follow code in your groovy script testStep to select a directory and get it back to your code:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser

// create the file chooser
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser() 
// set whatever directory you want where to start looking for your directory
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."))
chooser.setDialogTitle("select directory")
// filter to show only directories
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY)
// get the user action
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog()
// if the user selects a directory
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   // get the directory and start your logic
   File selectedDirectory = chooser.getSelectedFile()
   // sample print directory path
   log.info('Selected directory: ' + selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath())
   // sample print all files inside selected directory
   selectedDirectory.listFiles().each{ file ->
        log.info(file.getAbsolutePath())
   }
}
```

I don't know if there is something more specific for your case in SOAPUI API, however this code can do the trick.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks. I wanted this only :)

Comment: @Rushikesh nice to help you `:)`

Comment: suppose i have directory structure: abc -> xyz - > lmn. Now when i select a directory 'lmn' and call function list files like "chooser.getCurrentDirectory().listFiles()" then it's taking all the files in the directory 'xyz', but not in 'lmn'. I want to take all files from 'lmn' directory. Any suggestion? I tried to use  'file.getAbsolutePath().listFiles()' but it throws error.

Comment: @Rushikesh because `getCurrentDirectory()` gives you the current directory of your selected folder, not the folder itself. Use `chooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles()` instead. I'll update my answer to make it clear.